# Symbol width and height

Tags: html, css

How do I set a symbols width and height?

```
<span>&gt;</span>
```

that `>` is not wide enough:

```css
span {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Is it possible to set it with code like `width: 10px; height: 20px;` ?

Comment: Inline elements like span can't have a width and height - so you need to use `display:inline-block` as well if you want those to take effect.

Comment: Yea but transforming the `>`character to make it wider isn't possible by resizing the span. Just create an image and implement it into your html code

Comment: You should use background image instead. or just image.

Comment: The glyph for the GREATER-THAN SIGN character “>” has normally been designed to be suitable for use in its primary function, a mathematical operator, and it is normally surrounded by spaces (unless used in technical notations like XML tags). Thus, if it looks “too wide”, you should ask yourself whether GREATER-THAN SIGN is really the character you want to use. There are many other somewhat similar-looking characters that might better suit your needs.

Answer (score 16):

Set the font-size to 20px and then use the `transform` property, using `scale(.5, 1)` to halve the horizontal scale and leave the vertical scale as is.

```
span {
  font-size:20px;
  transform: scale(.5, 1);
}
```

or see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/b8beM/1/).

[image: Normal, stretched]

Answer (score 7):

`>` is a character. You can adjust its size with [font-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-prop) and [font-stretch](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-stretch-prop) (although it [has limited support](http://caniuse.com/#search=stretch)).

Keep in mind that the width will vary with the font family too.

(Be careful not to use a greater than symbol when you actually want an arrow.)

Comment: Yea and none of the common browsers support `font-stretch` property :)

Comment: font-stretch will most likely have no or little effect. The least standard fonts come with different faces. And the interpolation from browsers is - let's say suboptimal.

Comment: Yeah, but I think Quentin covers all that with "limited support".

Comment: We can also use `transform: scale` property it seems. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_scale).

Answer (score 2):

No you can't change width and height separately and this is for a good reason. Fonts (and this includes symbols as well) aren't made to be stretched. Doing this you would end up with distorted and ugly looking symbol and making all typography experts yelling like hell.
This is the reason why you can only set one value - the aspect ration will always stay the same. It's for us all safety.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible set the width of a character, but...

A little sloppy solution: why you not try with other font? You can find several wide fonts in [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts#) (under "wide" filter), and make something like this:

```
span.wide {
    font-family:"wide font";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

**Pros:** Cross-browser, minimal code, no images.
**Cons:** Using many fonts can slow down your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

try using font-size property in inline CSS.
for example.
`<input type="button" name="equal" value="=" style="font-size: 45px;" class="equal">`
most of the time it works because as you know CSS prioritize inline CSS more than anything.
Wish you a good luck.

Answer (score -4):

use css generated content to duplicate the symbol and position them ever so slightly off the content's center...actually you can use generated content here in a variety of ways to achieve the desired solution, i just chose this one to make my point. simply reapply the greater than sign using unicode characters and move them around to your desired size, like so

```
  
span{width:75px; height:75px; text-align:left; font-size:75px; position:relative}
span:before,span:after{color:#008000; font-size:75px; font-weight:900; text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000; position:absolute; width:75px; height:75px; top:0; z-index:100}
span:before{content:"\003C"; left:-3px}
span:after{content:"\003C"; right:-3px}
```

using the same markup shown in the question; working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/khAr3/1/

Comment: The question is asking about changing the size of the character, not the size of the box … and this doesn't even change the size of the box since `span` is (by default) `display: inline` so `height` and `width` do not apply.

Comment: A raw `>` is fine. It is `<` that has special meaning in that context.

Comment: On the other hand, it's best to avoid `>` in element contents, as it can cause confusion for readers. (Human readers that is.)

Comment: the question asked if you could apply width and height...i showed how to do that. totally forgot the display block, mb. not sure what "raw > is fine. it is < that has special meaning" this means at all. i dropped in ascii chars and stack automagically made them into < and >. a better approach would be to apply the the character using content:"", :before, and a unicode character that matches the desired size

Comment: Sorry, but after your edit your answer makes even less sense.